# Python File I/O: Implementing a function that copy's the content of one text file to an empty text file

Tags: python, file

Before I begin I would like to state that I am very much a beginner in Python. I am trying to create a function called fcopy() that will take two file names as arguments and copies the content of the first file into the second, when the second file does not exist at the time of the copy. Then get the function to close all files and open the second file for reading. I am using a for statement to read and print the lines in the second file. Here is what I have so far:

```
def fcopy(file1, file2):
os.chdir('C:/Users/Noah/Documents/myPython')
file1 = str(input('Enter file with text: '))
file2 = str(input('Enter empty file: '))
opened_file= open(file1, 'r')
for lines in file1:
    file2.write('file1')
    print(lines)
```

Comment: Is your function supposed to take the filenames as arguments, or should it prompt the user to type the names?  Your description and your code are ambiguous on this point.

Comment: Yes it is supposed to take them as arguments, my apologies I will update the question.

Comment: Also file2.write('file1') will just write 'file1' to file2 I think you mean file2.write(lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filenames are passed in as arguments; you don't need to prompt the user to type in the names.

```
def fcopy(file1, file2):
    os.chdir('C:/Users/Noah/Documents/myPython')
    open_file_1 = open(file1, 'r')
    open_file_2 = open(file2, 'w')
    for line in open_file_1:
        open_file_2.write(line)
    open_file_1.close()
    open_file_2.close()
    open_file_2 = open(file2, 'r')
    for line in open_file_2:
        print(line)
    open_file_2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to test if the file2 is non existent at the time of the writing and abort otherwise, you can make it with `os.path.isfile` in John Gordon code.

```
def fcopy(file1, file2):
    os.chdir('C:/Users/Noah/Documents/myPython')
    if(os.path.isfile(file2)):
        open_file_1 = open(file1, 'r')
        open_file_2 = open(file2, 'w')
        for line in open_file_1:
            open_file_2.write(line)
        open_file_1.close()
        open_file_2.close()
        open_file_2 = open(file2, 'r')
        for line in open_file_2:
            print(line)
        open_file_2.close()
```